# Scotts axiom, stronger strong representation theorems, trichotomys, regular trichotomies, for Qualitative -Numerical Probability function relations

Tags: probability, order-theory, axioms, lattice-orders, decision-theory

Scott's theorem/axiom and other qualitative to numerical probability representation theorems give conditions under which a qualitative comparative probability  ordering, (under $\geq|\leq $ denotes at least as probable than) can be **strongly represented** by some probability function .
  **strongly represented** $(SR)$
$$(SR)\text{where}\,P: F \to [0,1]; A \geq B \iff P(A) \geq P(B)$$

Generally it requires totality $(T)$in the sense of weak order or total pre-order.
$$(T) [A \leq B \vee B\leq A]$$ ).

**I presume this implies strict weak order?**
Suppose, one has something stronger then $(T)$, akin to trichotomy(strongly connex

where $\neg A\equiv A\neq B$:and $A>B\equiv B<A$
and  exactly one of
$$(T1)[A>B \vee A=B \vee A< B]\text{the ' or'is exclusive or}$$
$(1)\vee $$.

Holds ,where $A\neq B$\iff \neg (A>B \vee AB\vee B>A)\iff A\geq B \land B\geq A\iff A\leq B\land B\leq A$$

**$$\text{where} T1 \text{is the corresponding numerical probability  representation}.$$
$$(T1)A > B \iff P(A)> P(B)$$.

$$A < B \iff P(A)< P(B)$$.
$$ A=B \iff  PR(A)=PR(B)$$**'

$(2)'='$ d**enotes equal comparative probability** and is an equivalence relation  that is anti-symmetric (in  the sense that sense) like a strict total order. As below. 
strong anti symmetry

$$A=B \iff[ A \leq B \land B\leq A\land iff \neg [A<B] \land \neg [B<A]\iff A\leq B \land B\leq A $$.

$$A>B \iff A\neq B \land \neg (A<B)\iff A\neq B\land \neg B>A\iff A\neq B\land A\geq B$$

$(3)$ $'='$ and $>$ are basic and both are transitive, negatively transitive (and in relation to each other .

$(4)$ 
 $\neg (A=B)\equiv A\neq B$ 
and $\geq$ is redundant where it is defined as:.

$$B\geq A\equiv \neg (A>B)\equiv A\leq B\equiv \neg B<A)\equiv [B=A\vee B>A]$$:

$$A>B \land B=C \to A>C$$.

**complementary**  for $=$ and $>$and everything if and only if.$>$ is

assymetric.
$$A>B\rightarrow \neg (B>A)$$.

$$A>B\rightarrow \neg (A<B)$$

inversion asymmetric.

$$\text {inversion assymetric} A>B\iff  B<A$$.

**complementary (everythig if and only if ):**
$$A=B\iff \neg A= \neg B$$.

$$A>B\iff \neg A< \neg B$$.

which is considered stronger then de-finetti axioms as well 
**where it satisfies the stronger (than de finetti) addivity**. 
 $$A>B \land C=D\to  A\cup C> B\cup D\text{where}\land A \cup C=\emptyset $$ 
$$A>B \land C>D\to  A\cup C> B\cup D$$
 $A\cup C> B\cup D$\to \text{at least 2 of} A>B\land A>D ,C>B C>D$$

as 
 $$A=B \land C=D\to  A\cup C= A\cup D\text{where both are mutually exclusive) this is strict > if  one of the two are not mutually exclusive,} $$
**See chapter 5 in (under the QM section)**

*Krantz, David H.; Luce, R.Duncan; Suppes, Patrick; Tversky, Amos*, Foundations of measurement. Vol. I: Additive and polynomial representations, Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 0-486-45314-6). xxvi, 584 p. (2007). [ZBL1118.91359](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1118.91359).

THe authors consider  stronger then de-finettisaxiom

$$\text{de finetti} A\leq B \iff A\cup C\leq B\cup C where A\cup C = B\cup C=\emptyset$$
although it the stronger axiom above apparently implied according to  Terrence Fine monogragh

*Fine, Terrence L.*, Theories of probability. An examination of foundations, New York-London: Academic Press. XII, 263 p. $ 14.50 (1973). [ZBL0275.60006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0275.60006). by

$$ A\cup C= B\cup D\to A=B \land  C= D \vee A>B \vee C<D \vee A<B \vee C>D$$

**Is there a name of this property $(A)$ (strongly connex)?

*And is  a probability order where $=$, and $>$ are basic that satisfies $(A)$ (trichotomy so defined for a CP order) stronger than a strict weak order or a comparativee probability relation that satisfies the more standard $(T)$totality?** ?**

And is $(T_1)$ a stronger numerical representation  than $SR$ above?**

*Fishburn, Peter C.*, [**The axioms of subjective probability**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/ss/1177013611), Stat. Sci. 1, 335-358 (1986). [ZBL0604.60004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0604.60004). as $\neg B>A$ at the end of $(2)$

s)

*Fishburn, P.C.*, [**SSB utility theory and decision-making under uncertainty**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0165-4896(84)90100-8), Math. Soc. Sci. 8, 253-285 (1984). [ZBL0553.90017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0553.90017).

*Fishburn, Peter C.*, [**Intransitive indifference in preference theory: A survey**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/opre.18.2.207), Oper. Res. 18, 207-228 (1970). [ZBL0195.21404](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0195.21404).

*Domotor, Zoltan*, Qualitative information and entropy structures, Inform. Inference, 148-194 (1970). [ZBL0237.94006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0237.94006).

*Krantz, David H.; Luce, R.Duncan; Suppes, Patrick; Tversky, Amos*, Foundations of measurement. Vol. I: Additive and polynomial representations, New York-London: Academic Press. XXIV,577 p. $ 16.50 (1971). [ZBL0232.02040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0232.02040).

*Fishburn, Peter C.*, [**Finite linear qualitative probability**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jmps.1996.0004), J. Math. Psychol. 40, No.1, 64-77 (1996). [ZBL0851.60002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0851.60002).

*Fishburn, P.C.*, Utility theory for decision making, Publications in Operations Research. No.18; New York etc.: John Wiley and Sons, Inc. XIV, 234 p. (1970). [ZBL0213.46202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0213.46202). and it singles out more easily a unique representation in the presence of other conditions which often imply Scott's condition in any case.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For weak representations of the form $A \succsim B \implies P(A) \ge P(B)$ and $A \succ B \implies P(A) > P(B)$, which I think is what you have in mind, you are not in general able to recover from $P$ the maximally likely elements in a given set $E$ of events. But this might be important in applications. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are unranked but both $\succsim$-maximal in $E$, you might have $P(A) > P(B)$.

There was a similar situation in utility theory, where one is concerned with representing preorders of various sorts. For an incomplete preorder $\succsim$ (say, on a set $X$), focus shifted from finding the analogue of weak representations to finding a family $U$ of functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
x \succsim y \iff u(x) \ge u(y) \;\forall u \in U.
$$
The set $U$ is sometimes known as a *multi*-representation of $\succsim$. So in your context, it would be natural to ask under what conditions a set of finitely additive probability functions could play the same role.

Comment: Dear David,  Thanks for this; I presume you are talking about the focus that is now present multi-prior representations and intermediate representation theorems (which stronger, weak, and almost agreeing measures); insofar that they share with strong representations; in some cases, the fact that the inequalities and equalities (present in the qualitative structure), are preserved in their bi-directional form

Comment: The distributions themselves which are just qualitatively ranked ordered by the numerical chances; which are themselves linear do appear to have (what I call) some form of 'vertical or global additivity' ie quasi-linearity; funnily enough (by which I mean A itself somewhat adds up, betwixt spaces, and as the chance doubles,; ie it appears to have this property F(1-P)+ F(p)=1 and F-1(c)+F-1(c)=1; as well the symmetry property described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution. And possibly mirror or square symmetry (although presumably) not point reflection symmetry)

Comment: Otherwise, I presume, that without some weird signed charges trick, that would induce point reflection. Not much would come out, Even if I postulated, that F(p) and G(p) are (montononic strictly increasing, bijective; and least uniformly continous or more). This is because I am not allowing my self to use lotteries or weird additivity complementary events between spaces, unless its induced by the structure as it already is (to some degree). Otherwise one may well have a difference operator. There are other properties that it satifies of course G(p) is the function for ~A, and G(p)=F(1-p)

Comment: and likewise, it appears that they there inverses are essentially identical as well; and where also has the same symmetry properties, plust some F(p) +G(p)=1 iff (1-p) +p=1 (this is standard additivity when expressed in one direction, the birectional claim, is that they the credence of A plus that of ~A cannot sum to one at other, or betwixt spaces, where these repective chances do not). There is also an induced ordering on the sum, insofar that A or rather the set of credal A events F, and G, are strict linear orders, where this combined with the symmetry properties also ensure that some sums

Comment: where the inequalities are reversed x>x2, x1<x3, but [x +x1]> [x2 +x3]; often (but not always as far as I can see) implies F(x1) +F(x)> F(x2)+ x3, and likewise for G; this is somewhat induced by the fact that arbitrary two credences F(p) + F(y)<1|>1, F(p) + G(y)<1|>1,  G(p)+G(x)<1|>1 iff (x +y<1|>1. and likewise for the inverses which is presumably already expressed in the iff claim

Comment: At best, the only kind of (upwards/global) additive structure (or rather linear structure) it has is due to the fact, that everywhere is in an indifference class. So I know at least that (trivially) because they are ranked ordered, that these chance sums G(60)+F(60) will have greater function sums, as will the ordinal events, in any representing structures then anything lower (due the indifference relation and the ordinal ranking G(60)=F(60); both >0.5, and bigger (or smaller) than any other such class (and to the same degree)in the indifference class.

Comment: It could be that in the infinite, and and if strongly non atomic (in perhaps not the standard, sense or right sense)  that even  if F(p) respects the chances, ie strongly representable and F=G, ie if chance of ~A, =chance of A, that even if the Functions, F, G, or credence are enforced to be equal, which they are, and functions are mirror images of each other; and quite symmetry within) it is not uniquely solvable ; ie what they are equal to, is another matter....... Despite the events being totally ordered, i guess one needs the differences to be completely ordered in this case.. .

Comment: Usually this is conducted through addivity, but when there are only two outcomes.... there are no non trivial disjuncts (ie which do not sum to one).but of course this is not the, complete or real reason, (although not quite, but it is almost spot on).

Comment: The real reason as far as I can see, however, at least or so it appears, that  unique-ness results (or linearity or whatever) can be produced,  when N=>3, without splitting or lotteries/randomizers, or other weird conditions; (ie simply as a result of the ordinal ranked, logical entangled totally ordered probabilistic (finitely additive, albeit vertical infinite) systems in these, lexicographic, entangled, situations (within and outside the context of Qm). is that no atomic outcome in the set of states \Omega

Comment: Hi david, When you say >= maximal, do you mean in a multi-dimensional model where both are the necessary event; or are two events which are ranked higher than every other events, but there no ordering between them. such A >B>C>D, E>B>C>D (where transitivity holds but nothing can be said about where A>=E, or E<=A, etc)

Comment: Hi William, it will take me a while to work through your comments, but just to reply to this one: what I meant by $\succsim$-maximal is along the lines of your second suggestion, but a bit different. More precisely, an event $A$ is $\succsim$-maximal (in a subset $E$ of events) just in case there is no $B \in E$ such that $B \succ A$; i.e. no other event in $E$ is more likely than $A$. In your example, $A$ and $B$ would each be $\succsim$-maximal. But they would also be $\succsim$-maximal if you added $A \sim B$ (i.e. if you made $A$ and $B$ equally likely).

Comment: Ah ok i think I understand now; the issue with the weak representation being then that the numerical representation might render A>B such that B is no longer maximal; that is if they are not completely ordered; if as a matter of accident they come out ~, then I presume that is consider more acceptable, because whilst they were considered incomparable in the qualitative representation but now equal in the numerical representation, their mutual >= maximality, as it were, is preserved

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. A weak representation might seem to say that $B$ is not maximal in a set when in fact it is. However, you are not in general going to be able to achieve weak representations with the property you say is `more acceptable'. Suppose for example $B_1 \succ B_2$ and $A$ is incomparable with both the $B$s.

Comment: suppose that if the numerical representation ranks A and B1, as equally probable, then it would presumably have to rank A above B2 as well; which may not always considered acceptable despite the maximality being preserved; unless the>=  maximality of the  disjunctions are considered. come out ranked numerically. ie PR(A)=PR(B) then it  may be(IF A v B1) that is incomparable with (B1 v or B2) with both considered maximal  qualitatively, presumably though the the numerical  the >= maximality (B1 or B2 ) would be lost, as it would ranked below (A or B1), if PR(A)=PR(B1) numerically for instance

Comment: @ David Marr I was wondering if you know whether there is any specific convention or distinction between the notation for a words strong representation vis a vis $$(A)\succ (X)\iff  PR(A)>PR(B)$$ $$x=y \iff PR(A)\sim PR(B)$$, Strong representation according to how Fishburn describe it require weak order , buts its not clear if he means a trichotomous strict weak order, or other halfway house. I presume also thatn when order preserving functions are spoken (in the real valued sense) they mean order imbedding which are appear to strictly monotonic increasing functions. Is there a distinction